# mapbox gl-js: how to get the styles of points/polygons from mapbox studio and position it programmatically?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map with an abundance of dynamically generated data.

I'd wish to keep the styling for this data inside mapbox studio itself - but would like to position it manually (programmatically).

The best example I've found is this: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/ however the positioning stems from mapbox studio as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "position", exactly? Can you spell out more what you're trying to achieve here? What does your data look like?

Comment: Please check my answer as I think it clarifies my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manage to achieve the above by using [getPaintProperty](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#getpaintproperty) and [setPaintProperty](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setpaintproperty) where you can get a property from a hidden layer with something like

`mapInstance.getPaintProperty("hidden layer name", "fill-color");`

and set it with

`setPaintProperty("visible layer id", "fill-color", valueFromTheGetMethod);`

It's only good for a single property, so you need to 'manually' collect everything you need.